# "I'll stake you. Pay me back next time."

Tags: word-meaning

In the movie titled ['The King's Speech'](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/King%27s-Speech,-The.html), Lionel says,

> *"I'll stake you.  Pay me back next time."*

Isn't it "I'll stake for you" instead of "I'll stake you"?

I think "I'll stake you" is grammatically wrong.

Am I correct?

Comment: Worth pointing out that where I'm from (NYC), it's more common to say "I'll spot you"; I understand "I'll stake you", but I don't think I've ever heard it used in real life.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that in other parts of the United States, "I'll stake you" would be what you expert to her (particularly if it has anything to do with gambling, especially poker), while if I heard the phrase "I'll spot you", I'd assume there are two guys talking about lifting weights or something...

Comment: I think of gym junkies helping each other out with weights when I hear "I'll spot you", too. Where I'm from (QLD, Australia) we say "I'll shout you".

Comment: ...and in *some* parts of the US, "I'll stake you" sounds like a line from a bad vampire movie.

Comment: It should be clarified that the film's actors and scriptwriter were British, and the characters were Australian and British. As a native British English speaker, this sentence makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's grammatically fine.

> Stake (verb): give financial or other support to. (source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stake#stake-2))

Comment: Would you let me know the link of dictionary defintion? As I found in the macmillan dictionary, it is written, 'to risk losing or damaging something valuable in order to obtain or achieve something', which is quite different from the definition you wrote down. (http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stake_2)

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stake#stake-2
Verb #2

Answer (score 4):

*I'll stake you* is correct and idiomatic. *Stake*, in this sense, is a transitive verb which requires an object, the person staked.

*You* does, as you understand, play the Beneficiary role here—the “stake” which you need is provided to you, for your benefit. If it helps, you may consider *you* to be the Indirect Object, since that is with most verbs the syntactic function associated with the Beneficiary role. But that role *must* be expressed, and it must be expressed as an *object*; it may not be expressed with a preposition phrase.

The Theme role, however—any specification of the “stake”—is optional, and it *can* be expressed either as a Direct Object or with a preposition phrase:

> He staked me.
>   He staked me a thousand bucks.
>   He staked me (**to**) a thousand bucks.

---

Note that in a different sense, that of “risk” or “wager”, *stake* takes an obligatory Theme, expressed as a Direct Object, with an optional Goal argument expressed with an *on* preposition phrase:

> He staked his entire fortune on the company's success.